# How to extract the IEEE 754 float representation in JAVA

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm getting the IEEE754 formatted float value in two integer variables. The integers are 13107 & 17184. The integers are needed to be swapped. Now, how can i extract the float value from these two integers ?. The float value for these integers will be equals to 160.19 (approx.). My code provides a result of 1.1 only ..

```
              int buffer = 0;
              int float_value = 0;
              float result = 0;
              float value = 0, mantissa = 0;

              if (swap == FALSE) {
                        float_value = rec_buf;
                        float_value = float_value << 16;
                        buffer = rec_buf1;
                        float_value = (float_value | buffer);
                }else{
                        buffer = rec_buf1;
                        float_value = rec_buf;
                        float_value = float_value << 16;
                        float_value = (float_value | buffer);
                }



                String a = Integer.toBinaryString((int)float_value);
                value = Float.valueOf(a);
```

anyone help me out with this issue

Comment: What is the type and format of rec_buf and rec_buf1?

Comment: IEEE 754 formatted floating point value sent through modbus from an application in two 16-bit integers, stored in two integer(32-bit) variables in java after received it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the 32-bit IEEE-754 representation of a `float` in an `int`, you can convert back to `float` using [`Float.intBitsToFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)).

Comment: Yeah it works after i converted the received two 16-bit integers to a single 32-bit integer in java & adding your piece of code. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test program to clarify matters. I suggest using similar print outs in your code to check what is happening until it is working.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits(160.19f)));
    int a = 13107;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(a));
    int b = 17184;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b));
    int bits = b << 16 | a;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(bits));
    System.out.println(Float.intBitsToFloat(bits));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
432030a4
3333
4320
43203333
160.2
```

The first three output lines were to make sure the input values were correct and I knew which way round to put them. From the first, I know the bit pattern for the approximate value. Looking at that and the hex bit patterns for the inputs showed me which way round they needed to go. The fourth line shows the resulting bit pattern. Finally, I used Float.intBitsToFloat, as already suggested in [Louis Wasserman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342836/1798593), to get the float.